# Can I search for European train connections avoiding certain stations?

Tags: trains, planning, train-stations

With flight search engines, it is possible to search for routes excluding particular airports.  Is there an equivalent way to search train routse excluding particular stations/cities?  For example, one might search for connections between two French cities avoiding connections through Paris.  Does any search engine with such a functionality exist?

I am particularly interested in Europe, i.e. the area covered by HAFAS when searching through Bahn.de, SBB, B-rail, NS Internationaal, etc.  I noticed those search engines all use the same database, but are a bit different in their additional search options.

Comment: [Loco2](https://loco2.com/) offer "avoiding London" as a search option. Obviously that only works for their searches involving UK trains, and isn't a general case...

Comment: Very good question. The best (non-)answer that I can give is to use a map to determine likely transfer points for your alternative connections, and then try use a search engine while asking explicitly for connections going through your selected cities. For example, for long-distance travel within Germany, maps can be obtained from http://www.bahn.de/p/view/buchung/karten/streckennetz.shtml. If you have multiple most likely transfer cities, you will need to make multiple searches, though.

Comment: @DCTLib That's what I've been doing so far, for example Caen to Barcelona via Le Mans or Tours.  Sometimes this leads to Caen->Paris->Le Mans->Paris->Barcelona, though!

Comment: Avoiding Paris itself or avoiding Paris area? e.g. you do not want to arrive in Gare du Nord and leave from Gare de Lyon or even stopping for half an hour in Massy is out of question? Anyway, given the structure of the French network, it will be hard to avoid, you might be better off doing it manually

Comment: From some bits of the northern French TGV network, avoiding Paris is possible. Around Lille for example, or some of the North West. Others it's a huge faff as the lines just don't go that way....

Comment: @Vince Changing stations in Paris or London can be quite stressful, so it's worth checking if there are connections that avoid doing so, depending on how much slower those connections are.  I have no problem with changing at the same station.

Comment: [National Rail](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/planjourney/search) has an 'avoid' option, but it doesn't seem to accept stops outside the UK

Comment: One reason why this might not be common, is that it can be against the regulations for certain operators. E.g. in Belgium, with most tickets, you have to travel via the fastest or shortest route - which are the ones that come out of the route planner. You can't take a detour without buying two separate tickets.

Comment: I am willing to buy two or even more tickets if needed. But all countries I have bought point to point tickets for allowed tickets with 'via' cities, which allows you to select a longer route and prices the ticket for that route.

Comment: The [ReST API](https://inno.hafas.de/bvg-hackathon-2018/HAFAS_ReST_Interface_v.1.23.23.pdf) does allow for an option to avoid stations (page 23), so in theory anyone could develop a 3rd party routing website that allows exactly this option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Czech **Jizdnirady** ('Transport Schedules') website to achieve this.

1. Go to http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/vlaky/spojeni/
2. Enter your route (in this case `Nantes` to `Nancy`):

[image]

3. By default it would show you a route through `Paris`:

[image]

4. Using the *Advanced search* feature to limit the time you're willing to walk between two stops. This won't affect the maximum transfer time, just the time it takes to walk between the two stops.

[image]

5. Voilà! We now have a route avoiding `Paris`, which is almost as fast:

[image]

Comment: Does that mean it will reject any transfer that takes more than ten minutes?

Comment: While this might work for this particular solution, I don't think this is general enough to be a good solution. It is well possible that the station one might want to avoid has not a longer time of walk than other stations.

Comment: @gerrit it will reject transfers that take more than 10 minutes to walk. I think this solves the core of your problem.

Comment: @drat the problem with transfering in Paris/London is that you might be forced to take a long and tiring walk/metro ride between two different train station. I think that's the core issue here rather than avoiding a particular stop.

Comment: @JonathanReez I know, I've changed in both cities before, and it is indeed annoying. However, I always feel that the trip on the crammed RER is the real problem, especially with luggage, rather than the walking time. There's railway stations (I can think of Zurich for instance), where in the worst case you will have to walk 10 minutes for a simple change of connection, without it being an issue, so I fear your solution will filter out some other potential stations.

Comment: How can it reliably estimate walking time within the same station anyway?  That's going to depend on arrival platforms and position within the trains.

Comment: @gerrit I think it only knows the distance between distinct train/bus stations and assumes that all transfers within the same station are instant.

Comment: I tried this trick on the German (Bahn.de) site, also the one where you can select which transports you accept. It did still give routes changing in Paris with transit by metro, even though the metro option was not allowed.

Comment: @JonathanReez: "I think that's the core issue here rather than avoiding a particular stop." - that may be the case, but it is only one out of various possible reasons to avoid a given stop. As long as the question does not explicitly restrict the underlying motivation, it seems like a bad idea to interpret the question as how to avoid a long walk; an answer would not help visitors who want to avoid stations for different reasons, but at the same time, they might have a hard time asking a new question as the new question could easily be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper feel free to add your own answer. I've posted this one 2 years ago and I agree that it's not perfect, but I'm not aware of a better solution.

Comment: I do not know of any solution. I just agree with @drat that this answer unfortunately does not provide a solution, either, except for a very specific subset of cases, and thus outlined the reason.