# train planning using 3rd party HAFAS ReST interface frontends

Tags: trains, planning

Apart from various official sources such at [bahn.de](https://www.bahn.de/), [sbb.ch](https://www.sbb.ch/de), or [bene-system](https://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/query.exe/en?protocol=https:&L=profi), there exists a [HAFAS ReST Interface](https://inno.hafas.de/bvg-hackathon-2018/HAFAS_ReST_Interface_v.1.23.23.pdf) that offers options that are not presented in the typical web frontends.  For example, there appears to be an option to avoid certain stations (see also [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52320/2509)), to include/exclude specific train operating companies, to configure walking speed, or to filter routes based on expected occupancy.  All of those would seem potentially useful for "advanced" train travel planning.

Are there 3rd party websites that expose some of those more unusual search options to the public, for people who have no time or skills to use the ReST API directly?

Or maybe those advanced options exist in the software in theory, but aren't actually implemented/used in the backend for European train companies?

Comment: Looking from the URL, this looks like a hackaton project

Comment: @NicolasFormichella And maybe the hackathon resulted in a page somewhere on the web where I can search for "trains that are expected to be quite empty only"? :)  I suspect the public API exists independently from the hackathon.

Comment: The only thing I can found about hafas APIs is [hafas-client](https://github.com/public-transport/hafas-client/blob/master/p/readme.md) in JavaScript for select transport network... I don't see any usage for non-programmers though